# How can i make a Flash-free, basic audio control?

Tags: html, audio, browser, safari, jplayer

I need to make a basic audio control: one audio file, play and pause buttons, no more.

I cannot use Flash at all - this website will only be used if the client does not have flash enabled.

HTML5 does not seem to be a good solution because my target clients (who do not enable Flash) most likely won't have modern browsers. Even worse, Safari does not seem to play the best solution available (jPlayer).

Comment: btw, jPlayer works fine in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

The lastest versions of all the main browsers (IE, Chrome, FF, Safari, Mobile Safari, Android) can play audio natively using the HTML5 `audio` element (so long as the media is encoded in a supported format).

IE6,7 and 8 can only play audio directly in the browser with the help of *plugs-ins* (e.g. Quicktime, Flash etc.).

So, if you have IE8 or less i'm afraid you cannot play audio directly in the browser without Flash or another plug-in.